# When Login i am getting axios error " required request Body is missing"

Tags: reactjs, axios

[image]

***when I am trying to log in I am getting 400 axios error with the message "Required request body part is missing". when I test the API in Postman I am getting the response. my requirement is after login in with emailId and password I have to store the response data in sessionStorage. but here I am getting an error. I have attached the Screenshot of the postman login details Please assist me  how to solve this issue.***

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { FiEye } from "react-icons/fi";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState({
    emailId: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setLogin((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:8080/admin/login",
        {
          emailId: login.emailId,
          password: login.password,
        }
      );

     sessionStorage.setItem("data", response.data);
      navigate("/home");

      setLogin({
        emailId: "",
        password: "",
      });

     
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login failed:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex  items-center justify-center h-screen bg-black">
        <div className=" w-[25rem] mx-10  px-10 py-8 bg-white rounded-lg">
          <div className="mb-3">
            <img src={logo} alt="" className="mx-auto" />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div className="mt-5">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-5">
                <label
                  htmlFor="email"
                  className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                >
                  Email address
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  maxLength="100"
                  name="emailId"
                  value={login.emailId}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                  placeholder="Email address"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-8">
                <label
                  htmlFor="password"
                  className="block mb-6 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                >
                  Password
                </label>
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center relative">
                  <input
                    type={show ? "text" : "password"}
                    maxLength={100}
                    className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 absolute"
                    placeholder="•••••••••"
                    required
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={login.password}
                    name="password"
                  />
                  <FiEye
                    onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
                    className="absolute cursor-pointer text-black right-[0.5rem]"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <button
                type="submit"
                className="text-white bg-gradient-to-r from-teal-400 via-teal-500 to-teal-600 hover:bg-gradient-to-br focus:ring-0 focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-300 dark:focus:ring-teal-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center w-full"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

***I'd Appreciate Some help! Thanks***

Comment: The second parameter of `axios.get()` is the config, see the [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro). You are using it like it was the body.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Thanks for your response I tried but I am getting the same error. in mdn docs, it says GET doesn't have a request body. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET). but when I'm sending GET requests through Postman I'm getting a response. I am really confused. could you please tell me what is the right approach? how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: A GET request *can* but *shouldn't* have a body. If you have control over the backend, you can change to a POST request. Alternatively, you could try passing the body via the `data` config option.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would actually read the resources that you link. It clearly says: "Sending body/payload in a GET request may cause some existing implementations to reject the request — while not prohibited by the specification, the semantics are undefined. It is better to just avoid sending payloads in GET requests."

Comment: After replacing the GET method with the POST method from the backend now it's working fine. Thanks for your help.